# C# Unable to delete a pdf that was previously open in a Window

Tags: c#, mvvm-light

I have a PDF file that is opened in window. The window is closed and then I try to delete the file and get an error that is in use. There should no longer be a lock on it since the window that had it open has been closed. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I have a local varaible _window

```
private Window _window;
```

I have the following code that opens a PDF in the window

```
_window = new Window
{
     Title = "PDF Viewer",
     Content = new WebBrowserView(),
     DataContext = new WebBrowserViewModel
     {
          Uri = _pdfPathFull
     },
     IsEnabled = false
 };

 _window.Show();
```

The window is closed as follows

```
private void ClosePDF()
{
     if (_window != null)
     {
          window.DataContext = new WebBrowserViewModel
          {
               Uri = "about:blank"
          };
          _window.Close();
          _window = null;
      }
}
```

I have the following code that tries to delete the file that was open in the window and it always fails with the error "The process cannot access the file \\ServerName\FileName.pdf because it is being used by another process."

```
ClosePDF();

bool fileDeleted = false;
int tryCount = 0;

FileInfo targetFile = new FileInfo(_pdfPathFull);
while (!fileDeleted && tryCount <= 50)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    try
    {
        targetFile.Delete();
        fileDeleted = true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        if (tryCount == 50)
            throw (ex);
    }
    tryCount++;
}
```

Here is the definition for WebBrowserViewModel. This is all legacy code, I was just asked to add the delete functionality.

```
public class WebBrowserViewModel : AppViewModel
{
    private string _uri = string.Empty;

    public WebBrowserViewModel()
    {

    }

    public string Uri
    {
        get { return _uri; }
        set { Set("Uri", ref _uri, value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of 
window.DataContext = new WebBrowserViewModel
          {
               Uri = "about:blank"
          };

try using the already existing WebBrowserViewModel.

So try:
WebBrowserViewModel m = window.DataContext dt;
m.Uri = "about:blank".

I think that changing only the DataContent does unload pdf from the old WebBrowserViewModel .

Comment: @Emanuele, That did't help. Still getting the same error. I even added m.CleanUp(); and still no luck.

Comment: What component you use to show pdf file? How you read the file?

Comment: @EdneyHolder `WebBrowserViewModel`? Show that and also what actually shows the pdf in the view

Comment: @Nkosi I have added the definition.

Comment: @EdneyHolder ok cool, but what is used to display the PDF in the window?

Comment: @Nkosi The window is created using a FlyOut from MahApps.Metro

Comment: @EdneyHolder Right. That is what is holding on to the PDF. Consider loading the file into memory and not holding on to the original file stream. That way the file is not locked and you can dispose of the loaded stream when done with it.

Comment: Have you checked in Task Manager if you have an Adobe Acrobat Reader (or similar) process started? If the underlying control you're using is WebBrowser, then it doesn't render the pdf itself. It uses whatever browser plugin you have installed instead. It may not have closed when you close the window, you may have to kill it... [some details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37414776/891715)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem lies here:

Doing this:

```
DataContext = new WebBrowserViewModel
 {
      Uri = _pdfPathFull
 },
```

creates an object in memory which continues to hold the pdf in reference even when the DataContext is set to  "about:blank"

I would suggest to take a reference Variable and use it instead. Make sure to de-reference it once the Window is closed. Make sure that the Window object is also cleaned up from the calling function.

So this is how I would update the code:

Add a new private variable:

```
private Window _window;
private FrameworkElement _fwElement;
```

Next set of changes:

```
_fwElement = new FrameworkElement();
_fwElement.DataContext = new WebBrowserViewModel { Uri = _pdfPathFull };
_window = new Window
{
     Title = "PDF Viewer",
     Content = new WebBrowserView(),
     DataContext = _fwElement.DataContext,
     IsEnabled = false
 };

 _window.Show();
```

Now when we close the Window:

```
private void ClosePDF()
{
     if (_window != null)
     {
          if(_fwElement != null)
          {
             _fwElement.DataContext = null;

          }
          window.DataContext = new WebBrowserViewModel
          {
               Uri = "about:blank"
          };
          _fwElement = null;
          _window.Close();
          _window = null;
          GC.Collect();
      }
}
```

Comment: You answer shows me the issue which I thought of.Can you please show how you would suggest using a reference variable since the call expects a url

Answer (score 0):

What's your question?

If you want to know which process is locking your file, an easy way is run `openfiles /query /fo table`, and parse the output. See ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput for how to get the output. If it's a local process, one time setup is needed, `openfiles /local on` and reboot.

BTW it can be locked on both ends of the socket, and even in between your PC and `\\ServerName` due to network latency.

It's rarely good idea to use network share for temp files. Use a local directory instead. If you can't due to legal or other requirements, use RAM instead of disk, e.g. implement a custom URI schemes for the embedded browser and serve the pdf at custom scheme URL.

Much easier and less reliable workaround is retry deleting that file after some delay. I would use 100-500ms delays and retrying for 5-10 seconds.

Comment: I have tried the delay and that does not work. I am not sure how to implement what you suggest when you say to use RAM to implement a custom URI schemes. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @EdneyHolder Copy the PDF file to MemoryStream. Pass it to browser by implementing a custom URI schema handler. Here’s my old article which has a library I’ve used for Windows Forms: http://const.me/source-code/winforms-async-protocol/ Quite possible it will work for WPF-embedded web browser, too. You’ll need to change one thing. In CInternetProtocol::Start method the content type is hardcoded as `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`. To serve a PDF you’ll need different string there, `application/pdf`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in WinForms and the only reliable way I found to get around it was to make a temporary copy of the PDF and display the copy, so that the original was not locked.

As far as I could tell there was no direct way to instruct the webbrowser to close the file.

Of course, you still need to delete the temporary copy but you can do that next time your app starts, or keep retrying on a timer, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning the DataContext to something else simply orphans the old one, leaving it to be disposed of when the program gets around to it and nothing in your delete loop is going to do so.

You have an unmanaged resource here, the compiler isn't going to clean up for you.  You must explicitly dispose of the offending object and hope the code underneath is written well enough.  I have never tried this with PDF files, in my limited forays with XPS files I ended up with SSS's solution (temporary copy which can be identified/killed the next time the program is run.)