# Does MuPdf library have unicode or text search functionality?

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, mupdf

**Background**

I am working on a WPF windows application and I want add embedded PDF viewer with only basic functionalities including PDF view, text search and page navigation.

I tried embedded Internet Explorer and Adobe PDF Reader installed method ([this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37413861/add-a-pdf-viewer-to-a-wpf-application) ) but this method is not suitable for our requirement as Adobe PDF Reader has too may external links which can not be allowed because of the security reasons of the application.

Therefore, I am trying to use [moonpdf](https://github.com/reliak/moonpdf) library. This library works fine with our requirements but the only problem is there is no text search functionality in this library. (I think it shows PDF as images)
Then, I have download moonpdf source code and realized that moonpdf is using [libmupdf.dll](https://www.mupdf.com/index.html) wrapping to c#.
I can modify the moonpdf source code and mupdf source code for our requirement if needed.

**My Question**

Is there any text search functionalities in mupdf? if so how can I use it?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly extract the text from a document, the MuPDF library will do that. I believe it's up to you to apply your own search criteria after that. I'm afraid I'm not expert enough to answer the 'how to' part of it though. I imagine one of the mutool examples would be helpful here though. I'll see if I can get one of the developers to answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the basic mupdf library, there are several functions for searching for text. These work by searching a page for a text string, in a few different variants, and returns the area for all hits of the given text. You need to iterate over the pages yourself (in order to do forward or reverse search).

```
fz_quad hits[1000];
count = fz_search_page(ctx, page, needle, hits, nelem(hits));
```

That said, I do not know how or even if "moonpdf" has wrapped these functions.